# CSS on hover svg file won't appear

Tags: css, svg, background-image

In my case I have 2 separate svg icon file. One of them white color, the other one is orange.

This is first state of icon.

```
.c-icon-not-favorite {
  background-image: url("../img/poster_fav_icon_white.svg");
}
```

This is the hover behavior.

```
.c-icon-not-favorite:hover {
  background-image: url("../img/poster_fav_icon_orange.svg");
}
```

But on hover orange svg icon is not showing. What am I do to solve this issue. I'm searching on for a while. I didn't solved yet.

------ EDIT -----

I solved that problem with added extra properties to `.c-icon-not-favorite` class. Properties are; `width, height, position: absolute, top:0, right:1%`. After that it worked perfectly. It's ridiculous.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: please add a [mcve] to the question that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Are you sure your image links are working?

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm sorry. It's an enternal project of our company. And it's working on local server. So it takes long time to reproduce for demostration. I'm really sorry.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao Yes links are working, I checked them 2 or 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Most likely the issue is with the image file itself.

```css
.c-icon-not-favorite {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image:    url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Apollo_17_Image_Of_Earth_From_Space.jpeg");
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.c-icon-not-favorite:hover {
  background-image:  url("http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/30000/velka/dandelion-133684137252N.jpg");
  }
```

```html
<div class="c-icon-not-favorite"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take img tag with your svg inside a div tag with a class. On hover of div tag, hide img tag and show background image.
By default, show img tag with SVG.